# How to bulk upload entities and training instances to dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have to upload a  significant number of entities and training instances for them to DialogFlow. Manually entering them is not an option since they are in a language that I am not proficient in.

I have checked out the dialogflow SDK for python, but that too would require entering each entity into the block of code. Is there any means to do a bulk upload? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the entity editor, you can go to **Raw mode** and provide either a JSON or CSV to import. There is no similar capability for training phrases.

[image]